# Redux + Rest API + Realm JS in React Native

Tags: react-native, redux, realm, redux-thunk, realm-mobile-platform

I am developing an app that controls IOT devices via REST API.
I am using Realm database inside the app to keep historical data captured by IOT sensors. I also decided to use it to persist information about user and devices. redux-persist didn't seem like the best choice since the app will eventually deal with big tables of data of historical data.

I am now building my Redux actions with Redux-Thunk and I am in doubt about what would be the ideal workflow/data flow. I am currently calling realm inside redux actions like this:

```
function addNew(deviceIp) {
    const request = () => { return { type: c.ADD_REQUEST } };
    const success = (payload) => { return { type: c.ADD_SUCCESS, payload} };
    const failure = (payload) => { return { type: c.ADD_FAILURE, payload } };
    return async (dispatch,getState) => {
        dispatch(request());
        try {
            const res = await apiService.getIt(deviceIp + urls.general);
            // Convert responses to date before Realm Insertion
            const newDevice = {
                ...res.deviceInfo[0],
                host: deviceIp,
                manufacturingDate: new Date(res.deviceInfo[0].manufacturingDate),
                lastFwUpdateDate: new Date(res.deviceInfo[0].lastFwUpdateDate),
                firstLaunchDate: new Date(res.deviceInfo[0].firstLaunchDate),
                lastResetDate: new Date(res.deviceInfo[0].lastResetDate)
            };
            const addedDevice = await realmActions.createNew('Device',newDevice);
            dispatch(success(addedDevice));
        }
        catch (error)
        {
            dispatch(failure(error));
        }
    };
}
```

`realmActions.createNew(collectionName, newEntry)` is a method I have created to add new entries to the specified `collection` in Realm DB. I have one main concern about this methodology.:

- It seems to me a bit of an overkill to write objects to both Realm and Redux. But Realm will be useful to persist this data in case the user closes and re-opens the app. What do you think about the approach I am taking. Would you suggest anything cleaner or smarter?